# load xgboost model return NoneType

Tags: python, machine-learning, save, load, xgboost

I have a problem in load xgboost model .
when I save my xgboost model using `model.save_model("xgbt.bin")` and try to load it by this code :
`load_model=xgboost.Booster.load_model("xgbt.bin")`
then I print the type of load_model by this
`print(type(load_model))` and it's print **<class 'NoneType'>**

also when I try `prediction=load_model.predict(api_data)`
I occured this error :
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'**

Answer (score 5):

The XGBoost framework stores the model directly to the XGBoost Object. The function `load_model` itself returns the printed NoneType Object:

```py
def load_model(self, fname: Union[str, bytearray, os.PathLike]) -> None
```

Loading the model, as shown below, will properly return the object you want:

```py
import xgboost as xgb

xgb_model = xgb.Booster()
xgb_model.load_model(path_to_file)
```

Now you can predict as usual with:

```py
predicted_values = xgb_model.predict(validation_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

@JCZwiggelaar is correct separate the lines where you instantiate the object and load the models

`model = xgb.Booster()`

`model.load_model(filename)`